# How to detect a sporadic time series?

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity, white-noise

Could someone give me some suggestions as to how I can go about trying to detect if a time series is sporadic or not? Are there any tests for the same? Also, I think sporadic series are quite different from random or white noise series and therefore the tests like Ljung box tests do not work.

Could someone help me with some ideas to test for sporadic series?

Comment: How are you defining "sporadic"?

Comment: I mean something like an Intermittent time series where the peaks occur occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what kind of time series your testing for when you say sporadic, but one popular option for testing if a time series is composed of time-dependent values is the Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test.

$H_0: \text{The series is not stationary (series values are time dependent)}$
$H_A: \text{The series is stationary, evidence of no trend (series values are not time dependent)}$

A stationary time series is a time series:

> whose properties do not depend on the time at which the series is observed.

https://otexts.com/fpp2/stationarity.html

The site above is a good introduction or review resource for stationarity in time series.